# .NET 3.5 dll not found on .NET 2.0 Windows Server 2003. Should I manually add this dll to GAC or need to install .NET Framework 3.5?

Tags: .net

I have .NET framework 2.0 installed on my Windows Server 2003 machine. I have a source code which was targeting .NET framework 3.5.

My project is throwing error on the reference file System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll on Windows server 2003. It says System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll not found on Windows Server 2003 machine.

Should I just copy and paste the System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll from other machine and deploy this into the GAC to resolve this issue ? or need to install .NET framework 3.5 in Windows Server 2003 machine.

Please let me know which approach should work fine ?

Answer (score 0):

You should install .NET Framework 3.5 SP1, instead of copy and pasting the DLL directly, as it will risk having runtime error because .NET Framework 3.5 actually has .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 1.

Latest .NET Framework 3.5 update/patch is .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 (SP1), and this contains .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2 (SP2).

.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 installer download link is available at: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25150

Comment: Hi @Eriawan, This is production DB server. Will it cause any impact to the existing databases, if we install .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows server 2003, which is outdated

Comment: @Koolkumar32490 Your original question doesn't mention anything about the server is database server. It is actually a different problem/issue then. Please focus to only just one problem/issue and with detailed description.